# Highlight edits made to a text by the user in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor, diff

I'm trying to create an editable text field in a page which highlights the edits made by the user to the text as it is being edited. For instance, text inserted or changed by the user should appear against a colored background, deletions should be indicated by adding a colored background to the neighboring characters (or maybe some kind of symbol?)... It seems to be much harder than I thought to do this in Javascript, and I am surprised that I couldn't find any code already implementing such a text field.

Do you know of anything which implements what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at Google's [Diff, Match and Patch libraries for Plain Text](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch) which are open source and available in JavaScript among other languages.

[Diff demo](http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html).

Comment: I used `diff_match_patch` for a similar purpose and ended up creating a wrapper library to help with the "presentation work" needed to use diff_match_patch: [github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff](https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff)

Answer (score 0):

`Step1->`
Store the original value in a variable V1

`Step2->`
Store the modified value in a variable V2

`Step3->`
For each word in V2 [word are divided by at least a single space] check it against the V1, if it's not same HIGHLIGHT it with HTML tag !

Comment: We want to do this as the user edits the text field, and it would not be efficient to compute the diff at each edit operation.

Comment: in that case you need to monitor it in keypress, keyup event !

Comment: This does not solve the performance problem. It isn't satisfactory to compute a diff of two versions of the whole text at each keypress and keyup event.

Comment: That's really the only way - wait 2 seconds after keyUp and compare up until a change, highlight that change, then repeat...